# Constraining axis on rigid body

Tags: constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I've been trying to roll a sphere down a slope and I want to constraint axis of rotation (so that it doesn't veer off course) but adding rigid body constraints (generic) or regular object constraints (lock rotation and lock position) with values to 0 min/max simply doesnt work. The sphere keep going sideways and rotating to values that shouldn't be possible. Am I missing something ? Thanks :)

Comment: In the object panel, next to the rotation settings, there are some lock icons you can press to lock those selections.  Try locking everything except the axis you want to rotate around and see if it works

Comment: Tried it and it works, thanks ! :)

Comment: no problem! :) happy to help